# Is a primary key automatically indexed?

Tags: sql, mysql

Is it true that in MySQL the primary key is automatically indexed?

Comment: It wouldn't be called "key" if it wasn't indexed.

Comment: @Paul Tomblin - That is not entirely accurate. Indexing is an implementation specific feature of the DBMS. A "key" is a term used in the SQL specification to refer to the attributes that uniquely identify an entity. As it happens, almost all DBMSs implement unique constraints by also creating an index on the columns but that is not required.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes it is true. An index is required to enforce the unique constraint on primary keys.